# Не выходит создать правильный запрос sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, запрос

Имеется две таблицы: первая ips, вторая dates. В первой два столбца:
`ipId (int,PK)` и `ip (varchar(16))` . Во второй три столбца, `dateID (int, PK)`, `ipId (int, FK)` и `date (datetime)`. Во второй таблице в n разных строках может быть один и тот же айпи, но время разное. Необходимо найти самое раннее время у каждого айпи и вывести это. Я попытался сделать это так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, DATE
FROM ips
INNER JOIN dates ON ips.ipID = dates.ipID
    AND DATE = (
        SELECT MIN(d2.DATE)
        FROM dates d2
        WHERE d2.idIP = ips.idIP
        )
```

В одной таблице без ссылок я делал это по такой логике, но здесь так не работает. Еще экспериментировал с разными условиями и добавлением новых во внутреннем запросе, но тоже ничего не вышло и порой запрос вообще не выполнялся(очень долго грузился). Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то тебе тут нужно использовать группировку и агрегатную операцию. Точно не уверен в верности синтаксиса, но что-то вроде:

```
SELECT ip, MIN(date) FROM ips INNER JOIN dates ON ips.ipID = dates.ipID
GROUP BY(ip)
```

Полагаю, это должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо вам, это работает.